# How to Stop Postgres server on Mac Os

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos, service

I already have a postgres service running on my docker, i want to stop the postgres service that is already running on my local. How to stop the local postgres service

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Activity Monitor
2. Search for Postgres
3. Select the Postgres and click on 'x' mark at the top
4. Choose to Stop the Post Service